# laravel 5 relationship filter

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I have 3 tables: Computers, Flaws, Patch

- Flaws **hasMany** Computers
- Computers **hasMany** Patches
- Patches **hasOne** Computers

So When I have a flaw concerning a computer, the computer is patched, the problem is that when I try to retrieve the Flaw with it's computers and patches, I get *all* patched, related to any flaw and not only the one requested.

```
class Computer extends \Eloquent {
    public function patches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Patch', 'computer_id');
    }
}

class Flaw extends \Eloquent {
    public function computer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Device\Computer\Computer', 'computer_id');
    }
}

class Patch extends \Eloquent{
    public function computer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Device\Computer\Computer', 'computer_id');
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve, with this Eloquent query, **ONLY** the patches regarding the current flaw ?

```
Flaw::with(['computers', 'computers.patches'])->findOrFail($flawId);
```

Comment: If a patch is directly related to a flaw, there should be a relation between them... Currently looking at your relations, a patch is related to a computer which is related to multiple flaws

Comment: You are trying to fetch a relations who does not exists in your Flaw class 'computers', I can only see a 'computer'. Unless is just a typo in your post.